# Qt, как лучше изучать

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно быстро и не очень глубоко изучить `Qt`, подскажите хорошую литературу по нему. К сожалению, мой уровень знания английского не позволяет читать `Qt Assistant`, да и там, на сколько я понял, просто описание классов данного фреймворка. 
Очень хочется найти книгу или серию качественных статей по `Qt` без лишней воды.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что хотите по быстренькому устроиться на работу, ссылаясь на то, что знаете Qt?:)

Comment: Идете в книжный магазин. Видите первую попавшуюся книгу по Qt, и покупаете ее.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Нет, всё совсем не так. На данный момент нужно придумать как рендрить `Html` на виджетах из `Qt`, а это проблематично, когда не знаешь азы фреймворка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужны следующие книги :

- Qt 5.3.Профессиональное программирование на
  C++ - Макс Шлее
- QT 4: программирование GUI на С++ Бланшет Жасмин  Саммерфилд Марк
- Марк Саммерфилд - Qt Профессиональное программирование (High tech) - 2011
- Андрей Боровский - Qt4.7+. Практическое программирование на C++ - 2012
- Юрий Земсков - Qt4 на примерах

Answer (score 5):

Qt 5.3. Профессиональное программирование на C++ - Макс Шлее - наверное одна из лучших (если не самая лучшая) русскоязычных книг